# Navegación en Array de Datos

Tags: php, array, json, foreach, jsonarray

Estoy desarrollando un sistema de reservas y me he topado con un muro! Estoy recibiendo información de un archivo `Json`, lo estoy convirtiendo en un `Array` y estoy imprimiendo los datos. Todo esto con este código:

```
$data = file_get_contents('hoteles.json');

$hoteles = json_decode($data, TRUE);

//var_dump($hoteles[0]);

$buscar = 'Lima';

$datos = 'city';

$count = count($hoteles);

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) :

    foreach ($hoteles[$i] as $datos => $valor) {
        echo $datos . '=>' . $valor . "<br>";   
    }

    echo '<br>';

endfor;
```

Mi idea es recibir información de un formulario, en este caso lo que esta en la variable `$buscar` y compararlo con el atributo `['city']` que esta en los objetos dentro del `Array`.

La estructura de mi `Json` es la siguiente:

```
  {
    "hotel_id": 23611,
    "last_updated": "2021-06-08T13:23:46.000Z",
    "name": "Rosen Shingle Creek Universal Blvd",
    "country": "US",
    "region": "Florida",
    "city": "Orlando",
    "city_Id": 6449
  },
  {
    "hotel_id": 23612,
    "last_updated": "2021-06-08T13:31:16.000Z",
    "name": "LJs Ratxo Eco Luxury Retreat",
    "country": "ES",
    "region": "",
    "city": "Puigpunyent",
    "city_Id": 7802
  },
  {
    "hotel_id": 23615,
    "last_updated": "2021-06-08T15:07:04.000Z",
    "name": "Castello Di Roncade",
    "country": "IT",
    "region": "Treviso",
    "city": "Roncade",
    "city_Id": 7911
  }
]
```

**Nota: Solo estoy colocando 3 objetos de mi `Json` puesto que este es demasiado extenso para colocarlo**

**Acá viene mi problema**

Cuando intento navegar a través de los datos del `array` para obtener solo los atributos y valores de `City`, sucede un error y no me imprime nada. En el `log` me aparece como objeto no encontrado.

De ante mano, agradezco mucho la ayuda!

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Utilice `array_filter()` y pude encontrar todas las coincidencias del atributo `[city]` con la variable `$buscar` e imprimo absolutamente todas, me di cuenta de esto gracias a una respuesta que pusieron.

```
$result = array_filter($hoteles, function($hotel) {
    return $hotel['city'] == 'Lima';
});
```

**Nota: por alguna razón que no comprendo, no puedo usar la variable `$buscar` dentro del `array_filter()` por que me da un error de variable no declarada**

Y luego imprimo con `foreach` todos los datos coincidentes dentro del `array`.

Hasta acá esta la mitad de mi problema resuelto. **Gracias de ante mano por la ayuda**

Answer (score 1):

array_column te crea un array nuevo con una sola columna de un array asociativo, array_search busca lo que le pases en un array y te devuelve la posicion.
Cualquier duda me consultas

```
$datos = 'city';
$buscar = 'Lima';

$pos = array_search($buscar,array_column($hoteles, $datos)); 

if ($pos !== NULL){
    var_dump($hoteles[$pos]);
}
```

Comment: No es lo que buscaba exactamente, pero permite acercarme muchisimo a lo que necesito! Gracias @Pushuno